# Indices in Dirac's spinorial representation

Tags: spinors, dirac-matrices

The other day in class we derived Dirac's equation and talked a little about its relativistic covariance. In particular, we said that the electronic wavefunction $\psi(x)$ transforms as $\psi'(x'(x))=R(\omega)\psi(x(x'))$, given a parameter-dependent matrix $R(\omega)=e^{\frac{i}{4}\omega_{\mu\nu}\Sigma^{\mu\nu}}$.

I have an issue, which is probably a misunderstanding on my part of the use of indices: in the definition of $R(\omega)$ we are summing over both indices $\mu$ and $\nu$, so... *why isn't the quantity at the exponent (and therefore the whole exponential) a scalar?*

Comment: What makes you think it isn't a scalar? The Lorentz indices are fully contracted and the spinorial ones "descend" from $\Sigma$ to $R$.

Comment: It's a Lorentz index scalar, but a matrix in spinor space. This is just like the spin rotation operator rotation $\exp\{ {\bf J}\cdot {\bf n}\theta \}$ is the exponential    of a spinor-matrix valued scalar .